# MIPS machine code JAL

Tags: assembly, mips

I have the following excerpt from a code:

```
always @(posedge clear, negedge clock)
    if (clear) begin
        // Reset content
        for (i = 0; i < 512; i = i + 1)
            content[i] = 0;
            // Initial values for instruction memory
            content[0] = 32'h00221820; // add $3, $1, $2
            content[1] = 32'h00221822; // sub $3, $1, $2
            content[2] = 32'h00221824; // and $3, $1, $2
            content[3] = 32'h00221825; // or $3, $1, $2
            content[4] = 32'h0022182a; // slt $3, $1, $2
            content[5] = 32'h0041182a; // slt $3, $2, $1
            content[6] = 32'h1140fff9; // beq $10, $0, main
            content[7] = 32'h8d430000; // lw $3, 0($10)
            content[8] = 32'h8d430004; // lw $3, 4($10)
            content[9] = 32'had430008; // sw $3, 8($10)
            content[10] = 32'h; // jal main
            // Initial values for data memory
            // Mem[0x10010000] = 100
            // Mem[0x10010004] = 200
            content[256] = 100;
            content[257] = 200;
    end
```

and I need to add the content[10] 32 bit value for the instruction "jal main", but I don't know how to get that value or where the other 32 bit values came from. How can I figure this out?

Comment: Those are machine code bytes. Use an instruction set reference that describes how the machine code looks.

Comment: @Jester using that method I got the immediate to be the last 16 bits but since jal needs a 26 bit immediate, I added zeros in front so I got the hex value to be 0c00fff9, does that seem correct?

Comment: `jal` encodes bits `2..27` of the target. Whether your value is correct depends on the address of `main`.

Comment: @jester I assumed the address of main was fff9 since that was the immediate value in the beq instruction, but I'm not sure if that's how it's done

Comment: The `beq` doesn't use absolute addressing, so that's just an offset not the actual address. Looks like `main` is the whole thing starting at `content` so you can reference that.

Comment: @Jester if main is the whole thing, how would I get an immediate value for the jal instruction from that?

Comment: `((unsigned)content >> 2) & 0x03ffffff` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Although, if `content[256]` will eventually end up at `0x10010000` that means `content` is `0x1000FC00`

Comment: @Jester I'm still confused as to what the machine code for `jal main` would be?

Comment: You just need to stick the opcode part (`0000 11` binary) in front.

Comment: @Jester in front of `0x1000fc00`? that would make it more than 32 bits?

Comment: Obviously not in front of that. In front of the 26 bits you calculate using the formula I posted earlier. Or, you know, just extracting the relevant bits by hand.